# mysqli search like only works with 1 parameter

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli

I'm trying to do a mysqli search like query to search based on first and last name. When I type the first and last name into the search, I get no results. However, when I type just the first name or just the last name, I get results.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$name = $_POST['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$name%' OR lname LIKE '%$name%'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $url = '<a href ="profile/?id='.$id.'">';
    if ($id !== ($_SESSION['id'])){
    $pic = "SELECT profilephotopatch FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $pic);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $picloc = $row['profilephotopatch'];
    $displaypic = '<div id="userphoto"><img src="../'.$picloc. '"style="width: 100%;max-height: 100%"></div>';
    $output = $displaypic. $url. '<div id="name">'. $fname. ' '. $lname. ' '. $city. $state. '</a></div><br>';
 echo ($output);
}
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `fname LIKE '%bob smith%'` is not going to match `fname='bob'` but `fname LIKE '%bob%'` will

Comment: I've tried to use two variables for the name, and it doesn't work.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I need to use two different search fields for first name and last name with two php variables?

Comment: `fname LIKE '%bob% OR fname like %smith%' OR lname LIKE '%bob% OR lname like %smith%'` but deepening on how many people you get you may get unexpected return results. you may want 2 post fields so you are sure what is first and what is last name, not all cultures use the same order. i can see people searching for "bob smith" or "smith bob" or "smith, bob"

Answer (score 0):

When you type both firstname and lastname I believe your code will try to find fullname from `fname` and `lname` column which of course does not give you result.

For example, you store name 'John Doe' as 'John' in `fname` and  'Doe' in `lname` column.

When you are looking with 'John' or 'Doe' you will find it in `fname` or in `lname`. But with fullname, both column does not satify criteria and yield no result.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql's LIKE construct looks for similar entries, such as "LIKE 'bob'" succesfully returning 'bobbette'.  'bob smith' is not like 'bob' (it's the space, it always fails the test) and will not return a row.  Try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $names = explode(" ", $_POST['search']);
    $search_fname = array_shift($names);
    $search_lname = array_pop($names);
    if($search_lname != ''){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$search_fname%' OR lname LIKE '%$search_lname%'";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$search_fname%' OR lname LIKE '%$search_fname%'";
    }
    ...
}
```

If your search was "bob smith", this would return all rows with a first name similar to "bob" or a last name similar to "smith".  Might be many rows.  For example, "bob jones", "bob smith", "dan smith" would all be returned.  If your search was only "bob" and you had entries for "bob smith" and "john bobbett" you'd get both of those.  Is that what you expected?

If you expected just (for example) one row when you searched for "bob smith" then your query should be looking for AND rather than OR.

Answer (score 0):

Here, if I understand correctly try this explode valeu from input field

```
$search= explode(" ",$_POST['search']);
$name = $search[0];
$surname = $search[1]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$name%' OR lname LIKE '%$surname %'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using concat, you can put empty quotes between the database rows you want to search together. For example

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(`fname`, ' ', `lname`,  ' ', `fname`) LIKE '%$name%' OR lname LIKE '%$name%'"
```

In that example you can see the empty quotes between fname and lname, as well as lname and fname. That will allow the search to be successful with either searches like:

Bob Smith

or

Smith Bob

And you will get the results you're looking for.